# Имеет ли смысл оптимизировать функцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия

Читал в определенных местах, что рекурсия работает медленнее, чем обычный алгоритм. Столкнулся с такой ситуацией. Надо реализовать перебор для каждого значения в строгом порядке. Написал как есть не думая.

Как бы работает так как надо, но меня все-таки терзает рекурсия... Вот я и думаю стоит писать рекурсию для такого кода или пусть и так работает?

```
def get_option_number(number):
    if number == 50:
        return [25, 75]
    else:
        if number == 25:
            return [50, 75]
        else:
            if number == 75:
                return [50, 25]
            else:
                return [75, 50, 25]
```

Comment: В целом удаление одного элемента решается через `sorted({25, 50, 75} - {number})`. Конкретно на вашей функции можно уменьшить вложенность, если использовать elif. Ну и если решать для общего случая (не отсортированный список из более чем 3 элементов) - можно использовать цикл.

Comment: Тут в целом не понятно, по какому принципу у вас меняется порядок элементов, и не понятно, как тут рекурсия поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Непонятно, при чём здесь рекурсия. А если вас беспокоит вложенность `if`-ов, то можно применить словарь, чтобы использовать всего одну проверку, да и выглядит такой код короче:

```
{
    25: [50, 75],
    50: [25, 75],
    75: [50, 25],
}.get(number, [75, 50, 25])
```

Comment: только работает обычно медленней чем набор if`ов, т.к. является ничем иным как вызовом функции со всеми накладными расходами.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков с учетом того, что набор ифов сам внутри функции, то просто вызов метода get сам по себе не добавляет накладных расходов. Накладные расходы могут быть при запросе элемента словаря, но это уже нужно измерять. Ну и я не думаю, что конкретно эта функция - это bottle neck, чтобы в ней пытаться применить какие-то микрооптимизации.

Answer (score 2):

для python 3.10:

```
def get_option_number(number):
    match number:
        case 50: return [25, 75]
        case 25: return [50, 75]
        case 75: return [50, 25]
        case _ : return [75, 50, 25]
```